# List of lists: find combinations of elements

Tags: python, list, cartesian-product

Say I have a list that contains n lists. Is there a neat way get all possible combinations of those lists that have length n, each element keeping it's position.

Here's an example:

```
lists=[[1],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

output:

```
[[1,2,4],
 [1,3,4],
 [1,2,5],
 [1,3,5]]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lists = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*lists))
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first thing that came to mind:

```
def find_permutations(lists, context):
    if len(lists) == 1:
        for item in lists[0]:
            yield context + [item]
    else:
        for item in lists[0]:
           for permutation in find_permutations(lists[1:], context + [item]):
               yield permutation
```